# Get value of one bit from 32 bits

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

How do you apply a mask to get only one bit after you shift right? Does it depend on how many positions you shifted right?

In a 32 bit structure I'm trying to get the value of the 9th bit and the 10th bit.

```
x := uint32(11537664)

0000 0000 1011 0000 0000 1101 0000 0000
          ^^
```

So for the 9th bit, if I shift right 23 bits I need to mask one byte? That seems to isolate the 9th bit because I'm getting a value of 1.

```
(x >> 23) & 0xff
9th bit...should be 1... looks ok.
00000000000000000000000000000001
0x1
```

So to get the 10th bit which should be 0 I am shifting one less bit which does make 0 all the way to the right. But there is a 1 after it which needs to be masked. I figured 1 byte plus 1 bit for the mask but I'm still seeing the the bit in position two so that can't be right.

```
(x >> 22) & 0x1ff
10th bit... should be 0, but this shift and mask does not look correct.
00000000000000000000000000000010
                              ^  This bit I don't want. 
0x2
```

Link to example:
https://play.golang.org/p/zqofCAAKDZz

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func bin(i uint32) {
    fmt.Printf("%032b\n", i)
}

func hex(i uint32) {
    fmt.Printf("0x%x\n", i)
}

func show(i uint32) {
    bin(i)
    hex(i)
    fmt.Println()
}

func main() {
    x := uint32(11537664)
    fmt.Println("Data")
    show(x)
    fmt.Println("First 8 bits.")
    show(x >> 24)
    fmt.Println("9th bit...should be 1")
    show((x >> 23) & 0xff)
    fmt.Println("10th bit... should be 0")
    show((x >> 22) & 0x1ff)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the shift you get a number being `0b10`, and you only need the lowest bit. So why are you masking with `0x1ff`? That has 9 one bits, that will leave the lowest 9 bits unchanged (unmasked).

Instead mask with `0b01 = 0x01`. That only leaves the lowest bit, and zeroes all others:

```
show((x >> 22) & 0x01)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YgdZIyPyhBV).

Also note that if you just want to test if a certain bit is one or zero, you don't neccessarily have to shift. Masking by a proper bitmask that contains a single one at the certain position is enough. You may compare the masking result with zero.

The proper bitmask for testing the `n`<sup>th</sup> bit is simply `1<<n` (where bits are zero indexed). The 2 bits you want to test are the 22. and 23. bits.

See this example:

```
x := uint32(11537664)
fmt.Printf("x      : %032b\n", x)

fmt.Println()
const mask22 = 1 << 22
fmt.Printf("mask22 : %032b\n", mask22)
fmt.Printf("22. bit: %032b %t\n", x&mask22, x&mask22 != 0)

fmt.Println()
const mask23 = 1 << 23
fmt.Printf("mask23 : %032b\n", mask23)
fmt.Printf("23. bit: %032b %t\n", x&mask23, x&mask23 != 0)
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hAJhh8-IXiD)):

```
x      : 00000000101100000000110100000000

mask22 : 00000000010000000000000000000000
22. bit: 00000000000000000000000000000000 false

mask23 : 00000000100000000000000000000000
23. bit: 00000000100000000000000000000000 true
```

Comment: I thought the mask needed to cover all bits to the left after you shift. So if there's 32 bits total then I shift 22 and I only want 1 bit then the mask needs to be 9 bits.

Comment: @JimB Or alternatively compare to `0`, e.g. `x & mask == 0` (or `!= 0`).

Comment: yup, I always default to 0, don't know why I chose to write it as `mask` this time

Comment: @JonathanKittell Masking and shifting are 2 independent operations. Masking doesn't care how much and if you shifted. You have a number as the result of shifting, and when masking, you just use a mask containing ones for the bits you're interested in.

Comment: Yeah, just mask - don't even bother shifting if all you care is the bit-state of a particular bit.

Comment: Ok, trying to just mask is helping me understand better. Thanks. If I want the 11th and 12th bits then the mask is 0x300000 because I only set the bits I want to one. 
00000000 10110000 00001101 00000000 
           ^^
00000000 00110000 00000000 00000000 = 0x300000
x & 0x300000 is 0x03 which is correct. 

Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: @JonathanKittell Bits are numbered from the right, that is the lowest bit. I edited the answer to show the solution without shifting `x`.